# Paypal API Seamless checkout refreshed access token not working

Tags: java, paypal

I am integrating Paypal's Seamless Checkout and I've managed to make everything work but I have trouble when the access token expires (after 15 minutes). I use the refresh_token I'm provived with the login to ask for a new access token like so:

```
Map<String, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
configurationMap.put("clientId","xxxxxxx");
configurationMap.put("clientSecret", "yyyyyy");
configurationMap.put("service.EndPoint", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com");
configurationMap.put("mode", "sandbox");

APIContext apiContext = new APIContext();
apiContext.setConfigurationMap(configurationMap);

CreateFromRefreshTokenParameters param = new CreateFromRefreshTokenParameters();
param.setGrantType("refresh_token");
param.setScope("openid"); // Optional
param.setClientID("xxxx"); // these are probably not needed
param.setClientSecret("yyyy"); // these are probably not needed

Tokeninfo info = new Tokeninfo(); // Create Token info object; setting the refresh token
info.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
info = info.createFromRefreshToken(apiContext, param);
```

and I obtain a new, apparently correct, access token

```
{
  "access_token": "A015viTDABshWd.DfewYFkdCBzDc.SUqXKFubpNhazLPCHg",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 900
}
```

However, when I make my SetExpressCheckout request using a Paypal NVP request like this:

```
PWD=xxxxxx&
SIGNATURE=yyyyyy&
USER=zzzzzz&
ITEMAMT=123.00&
CANCELURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&
AMT=123.00&
DESC=Price&
L_DESC0=Price&
RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FPayPal%2FDoPayment%3FrateId%3D1901&
L_AMT0=123.00&
IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN=A015viTDABshWd.DfewYFkdCBzDc.SUqXKFubpNhazLPCHg&
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
L_QTY0=1&
CURRENCYCODE=EUR&
VERSION=106.0
```

I get a correct Express Checkout token, but the Paypal user session is not kept and I get a screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJB6h.png). If I log in I can finish the payment but it defeats the purpose of Seamless checkout. I should be able to extend my session up to one hour using refreshed access tokens.

Note that I don't have this problem when I use the first access token which is returned alongside the refresh token and the Seamless Checkout works fine during the 15 minutes that access token lasts.